# Odoo - How to add "code" field to Accounting Model

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, custom-fields

I am working on a module that will print some values related to the invoice.  The only two things that are missing in the Accounting Model are fields:

-vat

-code (Country Code)

I have successfully added vat field. However, get an error when trying to bring the "code" field. My py code is as follows:

```
from openerp import models, fields

class CountryCodeInvoice(models.Model):
# where to place new fields
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

# getting country code to the accounting model
    code = fields.Char(string='Country Code', related='res_country.code')

class AccountInvoiceInherited(models.Model):
# where to place new fields
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
# getting the vat field to accounting model
    vat = fields.Char(string='vat', related='partner_id.vat')
```

I have definitely messed up this part:

```
related='res_country.code'
```

This is the final result I am trying to get:

[image: This is the final result I am trying to get:]

Do you know any tutorials that explain how to work with related fields? Official documentation does not go very deep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related fields base on a relation on the model you're working on. Usually these fields are `Many2one` fields. You already used one for `vat`: `partner_id` which is a `Many2one` relation to model `res.partner`.
You can relate to other fields of this relation, like in your example the vat of the invoice partner. You have to use dot-notation like in the most object oriented languages.
But the chain doesn't stop on the first piece. So you can relate on much "deeper" relations. For example your country code:

```py
code = fields.Char(string='Country Code', related='partner_id.country_id.code')
```

Again it's `partner_id` the chain begins with. But the country code lays deeper in the relation chain. `res.partner` has a `Many2one` relation to model `res.country` which holds the code. Just use dot-notation to get to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to play with it tomorrow. How would you recognize the tree? I mean when I was looking for a vat I just saw it was within the "Partner". IN this case, I should go and look for code and then find a link to the partner (through the country)?
This thing destroyed my mind, or maybe I was too overloaded...

Comment: For beginners it isn't easy to find such relations, because Odoo is complex. Just look into the models and their fields and try to search logically.